# Java GUI program won't generate random shapes?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I've ran this and fixed these errors yet they show they are not fixed! Basically the GUI is suppose to have a JcomboBox where a person can choose a shape and that shape is drawn randomly multiple times.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Practice4 extends JFrame
{
private final int CIRCLE = 0;
private final int SQUARE = 1;
private final int OVAL = 2;
private final int RECTANGLE = 3;
private int shape;
private JComboBox comboBox;
private String [ ] names = { "Circle", "Square", "Oval", "Rectangle" };

public Practice4 ( )
{
super ( "Drawing Random Shapes" );

comboBox = new JComboBox ( names );
getContentPane ( ).add ( comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

comboBox.addItemListener (
new ItemListener ( )
{
public void itemStateChanged ( ItemEvent e )
{
shape = comboBox.getSelectedIndex ( );
repaint ( );
}
}
);

setSize ( 400, 400 );
setVisible ( true );
}

public void paint ( Graphics g )
{
super.paint ( g );
Random r = new Random ( );

for ( int k = 1; k {
int x = r.nextInt ( 390 );
int y = r.nextInt ( 370 ) + 25;
int w = r.nextInt ( 400 - x );
int h = r.nextInt ( 400 - y );

switch ( shape )
{
case CIRCLE:
g.drawOval ( x, y, w, w );
break;
case SQUARE:
g.drawRect ( x, y, w, w );
break;
case OVAL:
g.drawOval ( x, y, w, h );
break;
case RECTANGLE:
g.drawRect ( x, y, w, h );
break;
}
}
}

public static void main ( String args [ ] )
{
Practice4 application = new Practice4 ( );
application.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  }
}
```

### Error

```
Error ';' expected
for (int k = 1; k (

error illegal start of expression 
for (int k = 1; k (
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Should I make a superclass?

Comment: A superclass? For what purpose?

Comment: I'm new to Java so I'm trying to fix these errors and just don't know how to fix them.

Comment: First define the problem. So in that vein, why do you even have the offending line of code? What is it supposed to achieve? If you don't know, then get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is telling you exactly what is wrong: your for loop is not a valid for loop. This is not valid Java:

```
for ( int k = 1; k {
```

I'm not even sure what you're trying to do here so I can't give you suggestions other than to get rid of it and to start over using appropriate Java syntax.

Some side notes:

- don't draw directly within a JFrame's paint method but rather within a JPanel's paintComponent method. This will prevent unwanted side effects from potentially corrupting a Graphics object that will be used later in the painting chain to draw all components.
- I would not create a new Random object within a painting method. Instead create a Random field *once*, and use it within your painting method.
- Please put in effort to post only well-formatted code when asking questions on this site. Your code is all left justified making it hard to read and hard to understand.